# Why user.dir could be set to "."?

Tags: java, unix, ant

What could be wrong in UNIX environment if following command says that user.dir set to “.”?

```
/home/user> $ANT_DIR/bin/ant -diagnostics | grep dir
user.dir : .
```

If I run this command on different computer- user.dir is set to current directory:

```
/home/user2> $ANT_DIR/bin/ant -diagnostics | grep dir
user.dir : /home/user2
```

Java does not work also.

```
/home/user> java -cp .:$CLASSPATH test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:653)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:619)
Could not find the main class: test.  Program will exit.
```

Add current dir to classpath.

```
/home/user> java -cp /home/user:$CLASSPATH test
Hello World!
```

As you can see, java have found test class only when I added current directory, not ".", to classpath.

As far as I understand some unix environment variable has wrong value. But what environment variable?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with Ant, maybe in the way it interprets the current working directory (`.`) vs the `$HOME` directory?

Comment: Java does not work also. Please see my update.

Comment: what does `pwd` say? What is the value of `USER_HOME`?

Comment: pwd says /home/user. Variable USER_HOME is not set on both computers.

Comment: incorrect permissions on current directory?

Comment: You are correct! There was no read permission on /home directory for others.

Comment: try running set, look for variables with HOME as part of their names

Answer (score 1):

Just in case: the system property named "user.dir" should points to the current working directory, not the users home directory (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html). If you wanted to have the users home directory, use the property named "user.home".

My java test program:

```
public class UserDirSystemProperty {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    }
}
```

gives me always the absolute path of the current directory. I just installed ant (apache-ant-1.8.4) and the output is also an absolute path here.

The only environment variable the holds the current working directory is PWD, but even modifying PWD like this `PWD=. ant -diagnostics | grep dir` doesn't change things, it still prints `user.dir : /home/holger/Programming`. So this has to be something else than the environment.

My next guess is permissions: The directory /home/user is probably a NFS mount and the user running ant (some misplaced suid-bit?) has no permissions to access this directory. To test this: do a `cd /tmp` and run your `ant -diagnostics` again.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with that? Do you want the absolute location of the user dir?

If so just do

```
new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: Something is broken at the users site. The prorperty "user.dir" should contain an absolute path already.

Answer (score -1):

Home directory is set in /etc/passwd file.

parv1616@parv:~$ cat /etc/passwd | grep parv1616

parv1616:x:1000:1000:Parvinder Singh,,,:**/home/parv1616**:/bin/bash

You just need to change it with the directory you wish.

It can also be changed with usermod command.

If still doesn't work, please let me know.

Comment: I don't see how that has anything to do with it. The question is about a Java system property not being set correctly, not about an incorrect home directory for the user.